# Trying to access current git brach from a windows batch file and put it into variable

Tags: windows, shell, batch, shell-script

I am trying to get the current git branch name into a variable in a windows batch file. To do this I am attempting a for loop through each branch from the output of the "git branch" command and searching for the "*". I think there is some detail in my implementation that is keeping me from succeeding, maybe a detail of being inside of a for loop? I have two batch files below, one attempting to use `findstr` and the other using string comparison of the first characters. Neither if statement is triggered, and I think its either the variable assignment or the
syntax of the string comparison.

Batch file 1 (string compare)

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
SET variable="foobar"
SET currentBranch
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git branch`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
  SET variable=%%F

  SET result=%variable:~0,2%

IF "%result%"=="* "  (
  ECHO found current branch 
  SET currentBranch=%%F
) ELSE (
    ECHO Not current branch
)

)
ECHO END
ECHO currentbranch=%currentBranch%
ECHO variable=%variable% 
ECHO result=%result%


ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Batch file 2 (findstr)

```
git branch | find "* master"| findstr /B *  > NUL & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO I am NOT on master
) ELSE (
    ECHO I am on master
)


SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
SET variable="foobar"
SET currentBranch
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git branch`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
  SET varz=%%F


%%varz|find "* " > NUL & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO I am NOT on currentBranch
) ELSE (
    ECHO I am on current branch
    SET currentBranch=%%F
)

)
ECHO END
ECHO currentbranch=%currentBranch%
ECHO variable=%variable% 
ECHO result=%result%


ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an entire program to do this.

```
 @echo off
 set current_branch=
 for /F "delims=" %%n in ('git branch --show-current') do set "current_branch=%%n"
 if "%current_branch%"=="" echo Not a git branch! && goto :EOF
 echo The current branch is %current_branch%
```

It boils down to `git branch --show-current` and you don't need to parse the results.

Comment: searched a LOT for this answer...PERFECT thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The following is a correction of the incorrect batch above, i think the core issue was not using !variable! syntax for dynamic expansion:

```
SET count=1
SET variable="bullshit"
SET result="bullshit"
SET currentBranch
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git branch`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
  SET variable=%%F

  SET result=!variable:~0,2!

IF "!result!"=="* "  (
  ECHO found current branch 
  SET currentBranch=%%F
) ELSE (
    ECHO Not current branch
)

)

SET currentBranch=!currentBranch:~2!

set Branch=!currentBranch!
```

Comment: check out `git branch --help` .. :)